# Asp .NET Webforms is injecting code on WebResource.axd that I need to remove

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webforms

I am trying to make a small WebForms app. However, I am having a huge problem because there is a code that is being inserted in the WebResource.axd file that is causing me problems.

However, I have no idea where this is happening. In addition to this web Forms is also injecting an old version of javascript that I no longer need.

Is there a way to disable WebResource.axd? If not where exactly is it getting the content from? I tried doing a global search but I could not find the code.

Here is the code that is causing me problems:

```
if (window.jQuery) {
    (function ($) {
        var dataValidationAttribute = "data-val",
            dataValidationSummaryAttribute = "data-valsummary",
            normalizedAttributes = { validationgroup: "validationGroup", focusonerror: "focusOnError" };
        function getAttributesWithPrefix(element, prefix) {
            var i,
                attribute,
                list = {},
                attributes = element.attributes,
                length = attributes.length,
                prefixLength = prefix.length;
            prefix = prefix.toLowerCase();
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                attribute = attributes[i];
                if (attribute.specified && attribute.name.substr(0, prefixLength).toLowerCase() === prefix) {
                    list[attribute.name.substr(prefixLength)] = attribute.value;
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
        function normalizeKey(key) {
            key = key.toLowerCase();
            return normalizedAttributes[key] === undefined ? key : normalizedAttributes[key];
        }
        function addValidationExpando(element) {
            var attributes = getAttributesWithPrefix(element, dataValidationAttribute + "-");
            $.each(attributes, function (key, value) {
                element[normalizeKey(key)] = value;
            });
        }
        function dispose(element) {
            var index = $.inArray(element, Page_Validators);
            if (index >= 0) {
                Page_Validators.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        function addNormalizedAttribute(name, normalizedName) {
            normalizedAttributes[name.toLowerCase()] = normalizedName;
        }
        function parseSpecificAttribute(selector, attribute, validatorsArray) {
            return $(selector).find("[" + attribute + "='true']").each(function (index, element) {
                addValidationExpando(element);
                element.dispose = function () { dispose(element); element.dispose = null; };
                if ($.inArray(element, validatorsArray) === -1) {
                    validatorsArray.push(element);
                }
            }).length;
        }
        function parse(selector) {
            var length = parseSpecificAttribute(selector, dataValidationAttribute, Page_Validators);
            length += parseSpecificAttribute(selector, dataValidationSummaryAttribute, Page_ValidationSummaries);
            return length;
        }
        function loadValidators() {
            if (typeof (ValidatorOnLoad) === "function") {
                ValidatorOnLoad();
            }
            if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) === "undefined") {
                window.ValidatorOnSubmit = function () {
                    return Page_ValidationActive ? ValidatorCommonOnSubmit() : true;
                };
            }
        }
        function registerUpdatePanel() {
            if (window.Sys && Sys.WebForms && Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager) {
                var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(),
                    postBackElement, endRequestHandler;
                if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
                    endRequestHandler = function (sender, args) {
                        if (parse(document)) {
                            loadValidators();
                        }
                        prm.remove_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
                        endRequestHandler = null;
                    };
                    prm.add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
                }
                prm.add_beginRequest(function (sender, args) {
                    postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
                });
                prm.add_pageLoaded(function (sender, args) {
                    var i, panels, valFound = 0;
                    if (typeof (postBackElement) === "undefined") {
                        return;
                    }
                    panels = args.get_panelsUpdated();
                    for (i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
                        valFound += parse(panels[i]);
                    }
                    panels = args.get_panelsCreated();
                    for (i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
                        valFound += parse(panels[i]);
                    }
                    if (valFound) {
                        loadValidators();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        $(function () {
            if (typeof (Page_Validators) === "undefined") {
                window.Page_Validators = [];
            }
            if (typeof (Page_ValidationSummaries) === "undefined") {
                window.Page_ValidationSummaries = [];
            }
            if (typeof (Page_ValidationActive) === "undefined") {
                window.Page_ValidationActive = false;
            }
            $.WebFormValidator = {
                addNormalizedAttribute: addNormalizedAttribute,
                parse: parse
            };
            if (parse(document)) {
                loadValidators();
            }
            registerUpdatePanel();
        });
    } (jQuery));
}
```

EDIT: This seems to be part of WebUIValidation.js. How do I prevent WebForms from injecting this file?

Comment: What is the problem that occurs when this code is present. Maybe you should try to fix that error instead of trying to remove a integral part of asp.net that could lead to unforeseen issues in the future?